# scraping javascript:void(0) content using python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am making a program, in which I am scrapping a web page and the content is hidden from the original page and use to display itself using 
`herf = javascript:void(0)`
 link and the text is in `<p>` and then `<span>` tags.

Here is my code:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-Python-Developer- 
Cloud-Analogy-Softech-Pvt-Ltd-Noida-Sector-63-Noida-1-to-2-years- 
250718003152?src=rcntSrchWithoutCount&sid=15327965116011&xp=1&px=1&qp=python%20developer&srcP%
20ge=s').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('div', {'class':'jDisc 
viewContact'}).find_all(re.compile('p|em|span'))
results = [i.text for i in link]
print(results)
```

and the HTML page is here:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mt30 dspB f14 lH20"
id="viewCont_trg">View Contact Details</a>
```

After clicking on the link **"view contact detail"** it will show all the hidden content. Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: The only way to do this is to execute the Javascript that handles the click event - you won't do it with a regular GET request.

Comment: then how can I do it?

Comment: Use Selenium http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: actually, I don't how to use selenium!

Answer (score 2):

The contact details are not on the webpage when the page is loaded. On click on view contact detail the webpage makes a new request to fetch the contact details.

In order to find out which url the contact details are being fetched from you can open firefox or chrome and open debugger using right-click > inspect element  (or just press f12). Then go to the network tab. Click on "view contact details" and see what request it makes. I have checked it and the url it fetches the details is from is "https://www.naukri.com/jd/contactDetails?file=250718003152". You can get the file id which is 250718003152 from the original url "https://www.naukri.com/job-listings-Python-Developer- 
Cloud-Analogy-Softech-Pvt-Ltd-Noida-Sector-63-Noida-1-to-2-years- 
**250718003152**?src=rcntSrchWithoutCount&sid=15327965116011&xp=1&px=1&qp=python%20developer&srcP%
20ge=s".

So all you have to do is make a new get request to the url "https://www.naukri.com/jd/contactDetails?file=250718003152" using urllib or whatever you are using. The response will be in json. You have to parse the json and extract the desired fields.

Answer (score 1):

The hidden content is actually fetched with a separate AJAX call:

```
https://www.naukri.com/jd/contactDetails?file=250718003152
```

which returns an easily parsable JSON string:

```
{
  "hiddenFields": {
    "file": "250718003152",
    "showSendQuery": 1
  },
  "fields": {
    "Recruiter Name": "Malika Pathak, Himani Adhikari",
    "Contact Company": "Cloud Analogy Softech Pvt Ltd",
    "Address": "H-77, H Block, Sector 63, Noida, UP-201307NOIDA,Uttar Pradesh,India 201307",
    "Email Address": {
      "title": "himani.adhikari@cloudanalogy.com , malika.pathak@cloudanalogy.com",
      "src": ""
    },
    "Website": "http:\/\/cloudanalogy.com\/",
    "Telephone": "9319155392"
  },
  "sendQueryForm": {
    "formKey": "F53b54d385c47b",
    "extensions": [
      "doc",
      "docx",
      "pdf",
      "rtf"
    ],
    "max_file_size": "2097152",
    "max_num_files": "1",
    "fileKey": "Ue2777e04d3b690ecbc77607eb919c00",
    "fileKeys": [
      "Ue2777e04d3b690ecbc77607eb919c00"
    ],
    "upload_url": "\/\/files.naukri.com\/0\/saveFile.php",
    "file_url": "\/\/files.naukri.com\/0\/saveUrlFile.php",
    "delete_url": "\/\/files.naukri.com\/0\/deleteFile.php",
    "html": "    \u003Cform id=\"saQ_form\" name=\"sendQ\" action=\"https:\/\/my.naukri.com\/mynaukri\/sendquery.php\/SendQuery\/sendQuery\" method=\"post\" class=\"loginLay\"\u003E\u003Ch3 class=\"title\"\u003ESend a Query to Recruiter\u003C\/h3\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"row\"\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"rowL\"\u003E\u003Clabel for=\"eLogin\"\u003EEnter Email ID\u003C\/label\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"rowR\"\u003E\u003Cinput id=\"saQEmail\" name=\"from\" rel=\"required:1005,custom:1001\" type=\"text\" name=\"from\" placeholder=\"Enter your active Email ID\"\u003E\u003Ci class=\"erLbl\" id=\"saQEmail_err\"\u003E\u003C\/i\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"row\"\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"rowL\"\u003E\u003Clabel for=\"pLogin\"\u003EQuery\u003C\/label\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"rowR\"\u003E\u003Ctextarea placeholder=\"Query cannot exceed 500 characters\" id=\"saQ_query\" rel=\"required:1011\" minlength=\"6\" maxlength=\"500\" name=\"query\" onpaste=\"return false\" oncopy=\"return false\"\u003E\u003C\/textarea\u003E\u003Ci class=\"erLbl\" id=\"saQ_query_err\"\u003E\u003C\/i\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"row upload\"\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"rowL\"\u003E\u003Clabel for=\"eLogin\"\u003EAttach Resume \u003Cspan\u003E(optional)\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/label\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"rowR\"\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\"hid_container\" style=\"display:none\"\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\"saQ_uploadCont\"\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\"saQ_basicProgressBar\" style=\"display:none\"\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cinput name=\"F53b54d385c47b[Ue2777e04d3b690ecbc77607eb919c00]\" id=\"saQ_upload\" type=\"file\"\u003E\u003Cul id=\"results\" class=\"outputCss\" style=\"display:none\"\u003E\u003C\/ul\u003E\u003Cp class=\"supDocs\"\u003ESupported Formats: doc, docx, rtf, pdf Max file size: 2MB\u003C\/p\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Ci class=\"erLbl\" id=\"saQ_upload_err\"\u003E\u003C\/i\u003E\u003Cp href=\"#\" class=\"chk\"\u003E\u003Cem\u003E\u003C\/em\u003E\u003Cspan\u003ESend me jobs like this\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E\u003Cp href=\"#\" class=\"chk\"\u003E\u003Cspan\u003EI have read and understood and agree to the \u003Ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"https:\/\/www.naukri.com\/termsconditions#g1\"\u003E\"Terms and Conditions\"\u003C\/a\u003E governing the use of naukri.com.\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E\u003Cbutton type=\"submit\" id=\"saQBtn\" class=\"blueBtn\" name=\"sbt\"\u003ESubmit\u003C\/button\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\u003Cinput type=\"hidden\" value=\"250718003152\" name=\"job_id\"\/\u003E\u003Cinput type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" name=\"isSMJLT\" id=\"isSMJLT\"\/\u003E\u003Cinput type=\"hidden\" id=\"file_url\" name=\"file_url\"\/\u003E\u003Cinput type=\"hidden\" id=\"file_name\" name=\"file_name\"\/\u003E\u003C\/form\u003E"
  }
}
```

In other words, all you have to do is to make a separate GET request to the above URL using the ID you already have in the main URL (`250718003152` in this case), and parse the returning JSON object.